# Is it possible to implement a Nullable Type like NullableOfInteger in VB6

Tags: vb6, nullable

Just wondering if anyone knows of a way to implement a Typed Nullable Type like NullableOfInteger in VB6? (I'm trying to avoid using variants)

You can easily create a custom class NullableOfInteger and use its uninitialized state to indicate a Null state but this comes with the obvious disadvantages.

Beyond that I can't really think of any other ways? My gut tells me there would be no good way.

Comment: Can you use VB.NET instead? Or a `variant` type?

Comment: I use C# for any new applications but unfortunately I'm stuck behind a mountain of "legacy" VB6 code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VB6 doesn't have the operator overloading or custom implicit casting that nullable types in VB.NET utilize.  You really can't do it any better than variant.

An alternative is to choose a specific value and consistently treat that value as null.  In .NET 1.0 days people used to use `int.MinValue`.  I don't know what the VB6 equivalent is but I'm sure there's something.  This works and is not nearly as bad as it sounds (but nullable types are better).

Comment: I'm not aware of a predefined constant in VB6, but you can always use `Const MININT32 As Long = &H80000000`, `Const MAXINT32 As Long = &H7FFFFFFF`, `Const MININT16 As Integer = &H8000`, `Const MAXINT16 As Integer = &H7FFF`, `Const MININT8 As Byte = 0` and `Const MAXINT8 As Byte = &HFF`. Note: `Long` in VB6 is an 32-bit integer. `Integer` is a 16-bit integer. `Byte` is an unsigned, 8-bit integer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered your own question ; Nullable is a convenience - .NET has an implementation, VB6 doesn't (largely because of Variant). If you want a type-safe version for VB6, you have to implement it, and many have - I recall that a common place to see this sort of thing was in database APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Just another point of view

Instead of **Nullable** you can handle this by using **Optional**

If you define it as `Optional BLABLA As Integer` it will have a default `0` value so if its null or empty u will have a default value as `0`..

Here is an example that i made for my self! It might come in handy:

**Usage:**

```
ProgressInc ProgressBar1 'you can add other options if you want as shown below
'ProgressInc ProgressBar1, 500, 50, 25, True
'I always change Min value to 1 in my ProgressInc so if you even choose it as 0 it still gonna be 1
```

also works this way

```
Dim TheThing As Long 

ProgressInc ProgressBar1 ,TheThing 
'See no definition about TheThing except being Long type
'cause of this its value is 0
```

**Sub:**

```
Public Sub ProgressInc(ProgressBarName As ProgressBar, Optional Max As Long, Optional Min As Long, Optional Inc As Long, Optional Continues As Boolean = False)
    Dim Recent As Long

    On Err GoTo ProgressBarErr

    ProgressBarName.ShowWhatsThis

    DoEvents

    'Maximum ProgressBar Value
    If Max <> 0 Then
        ProgressBarName.Max = Max
    Else
        Max = 100
        ProgressBarName.Max = Max
    End If

    'Minimum ProgressBar Value
    If Min <> 0 Then
        ProgressBarName.Min = Min
    Else
        Min = 1
        ProgressBarName.Min = Min
    End If

    If Inc <> 0 Then Inc = Inc Else Inc = 1

    'When the ProgressBar value is at Maximum
    'Return to the Minimum value
    If Continues = True And ProgressBarName.Value = Max Then
        ProgressBarName.Value = Min
    End If

    'Checkout Recent progress (pre calculate bar value)
    Recent = ProgressBarName.Value + Inc

    If Recent >= Max Then
        'Recent value is higher than or equals to Max value
        'to avoid errors caused by this issue Value should equal to Max
        ProgressBarName.Value = Max
    ElseIf Recent < Max Then
        'Recent(pre calculated bar value) is lower than Max
        'So nothing wrong here, proceed..
        ProgressBarName.Value = ProgressBarName.Value + Inc
    End If

    Exit Sub

ProgressBarErr:

    'ProgressBar error report.
    MsgBox "With " & Err.Number & " number : '" & Err.Description & "' error occured. "

End Sub
```

see up there im getting **Min, Max, Inc As Long** and when i dont define them they'r having `0` as their default value.

Comment: This is a little bit scary if 0 is a valid value for the variable.

I thought about using the same thing for my Boolean variable but then I realised that since it defaults to False anyway that this wasn't going to work.